# Excel Formula to check value of two columns and return specific cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I’m trying to create a formula that will check two columns (L and M) for specific values (Active and Disabled) respectively. If Active is found in Column L and Disabled is found in Column M, it gives the Value of Column E.

I’ve tried using nested If statements with index with no luck. I have a table that has over 5k rows I need it to check and spit out the results in a non empty cell table format so vlookup won’t work. I’m at a loss. I’m thinking this will need to be an array but am concerned about the size of the raw data I’m working with.

Comment: If you have a lot of data, I'd create a new column that concatenates the L and M values, then you can use a simple VLOOKUP, XLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH as required.

Comment: `=LOOKUP(2,1/((L$1:L$5000="Active")*(M$1:M$5000="Disabled")),E$1:E$5000)` maybe. Though, I'm not sure what it is you'r trying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Excel 365, you can do:

```
=FILTER( E:E, L:L&M:M = "ActiveDisabled" )
```

to give all instances as a spill range.

If there will only be one instance and you want the first instance, you can do:

```
=INDEX( E:E, MATCH( "ActiveDisabled", L:L&M:M, 0) )
```

Comment: The first one worked. If I wanted it to print the values in a table instead of a spill range. How would I do that?

Comment: Hey @KyleDrew - I am not sure about the definition of "print", but you can select a range for the output and enter the formula with **CTRL** + **SHIFT** + **ENTER**. This will force it to be an array formula in each cell. However, it will result in N/A where it does not have a match and wrapping it in an IFERROR will not fix that. You may also want to have it select a target range rather than the whole column because calc time can get really long for the whole column.  e.g., `= FILTER( $E$1:$E$30, $L$1:$L$30&$M$1:$M$30 = "ActiveDisabled" )`